# Why does $\sec^2(x) = \frac{\csc^2(x)}{\csc^2(x)-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

> Why does $\sec^2(x) = \dfrac{\csc^2(x)}{\csc^2(x)-1}$?

I’m not sure why this is equivalent to each other. Can anyone explain?

Comment: Could you double-check that identity? As out stands, the tight-hand side is $0$. Also, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @J.G. missing brackets

Answer (score 1):

$$\sec^2(x)= \dfrac{1}{\cos^2(x)} = \dfrac{1}{1-\sin^2(x)} = \dfrac{\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}}{\frac{1}{\sin^2(x)}-1}=\dfrac{\csc^2(x)}{\csc^2(x)-1}$$